# Delete duplicates from a list of pairs with a SameTest

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of pairs, for example like this:

```
list = {{1, 1.1}, {1.00001, 1.1000001}, {2, 1}}
```

I would like to delete a pair which is lies within a certain range of a previous pair (comparing the first element of each pair would be enough). So I would like somehow to implement a `SameTest` for the first element of each pair.

In my example the first two pairs should be consideres the same and one of them should be deleted. So my wished output would be:

> `{{1, 1.1}, {2, 1}}`

I tried to use `Union` and `DeleteDuplicates` with a `SameTest`, but they only work if I flatten the list, but I would like to keep the structure.

Then I tried

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, First]
```

with works fine (keeps the structure), but it only works if the elements of the list are exactly the same.

I failed to combine a `SameTest` with `DeleteDuplicatesBy`.

Is there any neat way to do this?

Edit: note that I have a list of pairs

Comment: `DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, Round@*First]`?

Comment: Like @Kuba said: `delDuplicates[ list_, rd_:0.1 ] := DeleteDuplicatesBy[ list, Round[ First @ #, rd ]&`?

Comment: Thanks, that almost works ;) However I would like to control the approximation: Everything which is the same within  plus/minus 10^(-4) or so

Comment: @Luke In the above `delDuplicates[ ]` function you can specify `rd`to do this, e.g. `delDuplicates[ list, 0.0001 ]` - is that what you want?

Comment: Ah sorry we were commenting at the same time :) Yes it works, thank you alot!

Comment: not exactly as I have a list of pairs, The question you indicate I could have solved with a SameTest and Union.

Comment: Since you are applying Rounding anyway, you can apply it composed with `First` and go with `Union` or whatever method you want. Although I'm not an expert and don't know which method  would be better where I will go now ;-)

Comment: To control the (absolute) error do `p DeleteDuplicatesBy[list/p, Round@*First]` where `p` is e.g. `10^4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to compare the **relative difference**, instead of the absolute difference, here is an easy way.  Use [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html) to set how many digits should agree for two quantities to be considered the same.

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, SetPrecision[#, 6] &]  (* fails *)
DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, SetPrecision[#, 5] &]  (* succeeds *)
(*
  {{1, 1.1}, {1.00001, 1.1}, {2, 1}}
  {{1, 1.1}, {2, 1}}
*)
```

---

Originally I thought I could use `` Internal`$SameQTolerance `` or `` Internal`$EqualTolerance ``, but `DeleteDuplicates` must do something like auto-compile (or reset the tolerance) on arrays that can be packed.  While the approach works on the OP's example, it does not work on the following.

```
SeedRandom[0];
list2 = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {2000, 2}];

Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = $MachinePrecision - 2},
 DeleteDuplicates[Prepend[list2, {1., 1.}], Equal] // Length
 ]
(*  2001  *)

Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = $MachinePrecision - 2},
 DeleteDuplicates[Prepend[list2, {1, 1}], Equal] // Length
 ]
(*  1074  *)
```

Also `Equal` and `SameQ` are special cases when passed as a second argument, but not when wrapped in `Function`:

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = $MachinePrecision - 2},
 DeleteDuplicates[Prepend[list2, {1., 1.}], Equal[##] &] // Length
 ]
(*  1074  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to accomplish your task. Here is one.

```
pairs = {{1, 1.1}, {1.00001, 1.1000001}, {2, 1}};
DeleteDuplicates[pairs, Norm[#1 - #2] < .001 &]
```

> `{{1, 1.1}, {2, 1}}`